# How to fetch a select tag value from child page javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a parent page where a select tag is there. It has a number of options. Now the user can select one of the options.

But the problem is the select tag doesnt have an id instead it has a name which is generated in runtime.

Now i want to fetch the selected value from child page javascript. 
Can anyone please provide me the pointers for this?

Answer (score 1):

Given the select element `sel`, you would get that as follows

```
var idx=sel.selectedIndex;
var value=sel.options[idx].value;
```

You could obtain the `sel` element by giving it an id and using `document.getElementById()`, or via `document.forms['formname'].elements['elementname']`

Comment: Thanks a ton Paul.
Can you please also tell me how to fetch the value of the below textarea field in child page javascript?
<textarea autopostback="0" title="Object Picker" onkeydown="return onKeyDownRw(this, 'ctl00_m_g_a6d75a1b_8678_47eb_88aa_4ddb5292a25f_ctl00_FormField13_ctl00_ctl00', 3, true, event);" tabindex="1" id="ctl00_m_g_a6d75a1b_8678_47eb_88aa_4ddb5292a25f_ctl00_FormField13_ctl00_ctl00_downlevelTextBox" cols="20" rows="1" name="ctl00$m$g_a6d75a1b_8678_47eb_88aa_4ddb5292a25f$ctl00$FormField13$ctl00$ctl00$downlevelTextBox"/>